# How do you implement this simple trie node in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for sequences of integer indices. For the sake of efficiency, it's important that the node's children be associated with the node via an indexed sequence, not some sort of map. To illustrate the basic idea, here is an implementation in Ruby:

```
require 'virtus'

class TrieNode
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :terminal, Boolean, default: false
  attribute :children, Array,   default: []

  def add(i, vec)
    if i == vec.length
      terminal = true
    else
      ( children[vec[i]] ||= TrieNode.new ).add i + 1, vec
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the same thing in Perl:

```
package TrieNode;
use Moo;

has terminal => ( is => 'rw' );
has children => ( is => 'ro', default => sub { [] } );

sub add {
   my ( $self, $i, $vec ) = @_;
   if ( $i == @$vec ) {
      $self->terminal(1);
   }
   else {
      ( $self->children->[ $vec->[$i] ] //= TrieNode->new )->add( ++$i, $vec );
   }
}

'wheee!!!';
```

And here is one of my various attempts to implement this in Rust:

```
struct TrieNode {
    children: Vec<Option<TrieNode>>,
    terminal: bool
}

impl TrieNode {
    fn new() -> TrieNode { TrieNode { children: vec![], terminal: false } }
    fn add(&mut self, i: usize, s: &Vec<usize>) {
        if s.len() == i {
            self.terminal = true;
        } else {
            let j = s[i];
            let k = j - 1;
            let ref mut c = self.children;
            while c.len() < k {
                c.push(None);
            }
            if c.len() < j {
                let mut n = TrieNode::new();
                n.add( i + 1, s );
                c.push(Some(n));
            } else {
                let ref o = c[j];
                match o {
                    Some(ref mut n) => {
                        n.add( i + 1, s );
                    },
                    None => {
                        let mut n = TrieNode::new();
                        n.add( i + 1, s );
                        c.remove(j);
                        c.insert(j, Some(n));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, here are the compilation errors for that attempt:

```
file_toy (master #) $ cargo build
   Compiling file_toy v0.1.0 (file:///Users/houghton/playground/file_toy)
src/main.rs:27:21: 27:36 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&_`,
    found `core::option::Option<_>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:27                     Some(ref mut n) => {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:27:21: 27:36 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:30:21: 30:25 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&_`,
    found `core::option::Option<_>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:30                     None => {
                                   ^~~~
src/main.rs:30:21: 30:25 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:28:27: 28:30 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
src/main.rs:28                         n.add( i + 1, s );
                                         ^~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
error: Could not compile `file_toy`.
```

The intended use of this is a Rust implementation of [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Anagrams). The trie, once fully stuffed with sequences, will be immutable and will live for the lifetime of the program. I'm doing this to learn Rust, so the more of my stupidity you can knock down the better. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your control flow is a bit convoluted, and there is a lot of nesting. By reducing nesting and unwinding the control flow we can get something a bit more palatable. I would also prefer to avoid all the redundancy.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
struct TrieNode {
    children: Vec<Option<TrieNode>>,
    terminal: bool
}

impl TrieNode {
    pub fn add(&mut self, element: &[usize]) {
        if element.len() == 0 {
            self.terminal = true;
            return;
        }

        let ref mut c = self.children; 

        let value = element[0];

        //  Ensure there is at least "value" children
        if c.len() < value { c.resize(value, None); }

        //  Ensure the "value"th child is a full TrieNode
        if c[value - 1].is_none() {
            c[value - 1] = Some(TrieNode::default());
        }

        c[value - 1].as_mut().unwrap().add(&element[1..]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = TrieNode::default();
    t.add(&[1, 2]);
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

The annoying bit is the latter 6 lines of `add`. A `match` is conceptually more elegant, however you cannot borrow `c[value - 1]` for the duration of the `match` AND modify it in the `None` branch because borrow checking is not "path-aware" but only "scope-aware" (a limitation that might be lifted in the future but we have to contend with for now).

For pieces of advice:

- Check for existing methods as much as possible. For example, using `Vec::resize` rather than a `while` loop conveys intent more accurately.
- Check for existing traits, when `new()` takes no parameter, it's better to implement the `Default` trait instead (opens more doors); also, `Default` can regularly be derived so that you don't even have to type it out!
- Use slices when ownership of `String`/`Vec` is not required. On top of making the code more generic (any type that is dereferenceable to a slice will work), here we also benefit from the indexing notation `[1..]` to cheaply cut off the first element and thus avoid carrying around an extra index.

All of that makes the code much shorter, and less code generally means less chances for bugs to slip in. Especially when duplication is avoided.

---

On another note, if you are willing to use either `HashMap` or `BTreeMap` for children, you can get "sparseness" for free and much easier methods for adding. For example, the `add` method revised with `use std::collections::HashMap`:

```
impl TrieNode {
    pub fn add(&mut self, element: &[usize]) {
        if element.len() == 0 {
            self.terminal = true;
            return;
        }

        self.children
            .entry(element[0])
            .or_insert(TrieNode::default())
            .add(&element[1..]);
    }
}
```

Much, *much*, simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, Matthieu. I've chosen this one because it's shorter and ends up teach me more Rust. The `resize` method and the solution to how to actually mutate the children vector are very useful. I'd thought I could borrow a mutable reference in an outer scope and then refer to it in the inner match scope, but this counted as two borrowings.

Comment: Incidentally, I find Rust's documentation comprehensive but it doesn't surface the more useful, interesting, or unexpected bits, at least for me. I didn't know to look for `resize` or the `Default` trait. As for using a map rather than a vector, that would come at a computational cost for my use that would negate the value of using Rust. As you can imagine when you compare the Rust code to the Ruby and Perl code I included, I started with what I considered simplicity and elegance and added ugliness incrementally as I tried to satisfy the borrow checker.

Comment: Is taking a subrange of a slice cheaper than passing and incrementing an index variable? As I have said, this is a case where I want maximum efficiency, so elegance at the cost of efficiency is not a good trade.

Comment: @dfhoughton: A slice is (literally) just a size and a pointer, so it's about as cheap as passing an index. As for the hash-map vs vector, it really depends on the range of the values you pass; what's the range of those `usize`? If the range is small, then a vector will be more appropriate; if the range is large, then a hash-map will be more appropriate (because the vector consumes too much memory and blows up caches). Finding the tipping point will require experimentation.

Comment: In this case, the range will be as large as the character set of a language with an alphabetic, or [abjadic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abjadic) or syllabic, writing system, so small. So for English no vector will be more than 26 items long (punctuation and whitespace is disregarded).

Comment: @dfhoughton: then indeed a vector might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `o` is a reference (`&`) but you are matching with a `Option` value (not a reference).

If you add a reference (`&Some(ref mut n)`), you will get another error because you are taking a mutable reference to `n` but `o` is immutable.

If you make `o` mutable (`let o = &mut c[j]`), you cannot change `c` in the `None` branch because `o` has a mutable borrow of `c`.

One solution is to take the ownership of `c[j]` (this would be annoying
 if `c` values was not `Option`), and give it back in the `Some` branch.

```
impl TrieNode {
    fn new() -> TrieNode { TrieNode { children: vec![], terminal: false } }
    fn add(&mut self, i: usize, s: &Vec<usize>) {
        if s.len() == i {
            self.terminal = true;
        } else {
            let j = s[i];
            let k = j - 1;
            let ref mut c = self.children;
            while c.len() < k {
                c.push(None);
            }
            if c.len() < j {
                let mut n = TrieNode::new();
                n.add( i + 1, s );
                c.push(Some(n));
            } else {
                match c[j].take() {
                    Some(mut n) => {
                        n.add( i + 1, s );
                        c[j] = Some(n)
                    },
                    None => {
                        let mut n = TrieNode::new();
                        n.add( i + 1, s );
                        c[j] = Some(n);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain "One solution is to take the ownership of c[j] (this would be annoying if c values was not Option), and give it back in the Some branch" in more detail? Do I understand correctly that taking ownership of `c[j]` means "letting" it like so? `let ref mut mineNow = c[j]` What constitutes giving ownership back? Going out of scope?